# the -= operator not working properly, not incrementing when its supposed to be

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

The program is supposed to make heroes fight against each other and the winner and number of rounds that took them to fight against each other and won is displayed.
Like in this format;

```
Ancient Battle! Achilles vs Hector : Winner is Hector in 4 rounds. 

The thing is, the program would print out like this :

Greek Heroes
Quarter Finals
Ancient Battle!  vs Hector : Winner is  in 7 rounds.                             
Ancient Battle! Achilles vs Hector : Winner is Hector in 4 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Hercules vs Theseus : Winner is Hercules in 3 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Odysseus vs Ajax : Winner is Ajax in 3 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Atalanta vs Hippolyta : Winner is Atalanta in 3 rounds. 

Semi Finals
Ancient Battle! Hector vs Hercules : Winner is Hector in 6 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Ajax vs Atalanta : Winner is Ajax in 2 rounds. 

Finals
Ancient Battle! Hector vs Ajax : Winner is Hector in 3 rounds.



However, what it should logically print out is :

Greek Heroes
Quarter Finals
Ancient Battle! vs Hector : Winner is in 7 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Achilles vs Hector : Winner is Hector in 4 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Hercules vs Theseus : Winner is Hercules in 4 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Odysseus vs Ajax : Winner is Ajax in 3 rounds. 
Ancient Battle! Atalanta vs Hippolyta : Winner is Atalanta in 4 rounds. 

Semi Finals
Ancient Battle! Hector vs Hercules : Winner is Hector in 7 rounds. 

Ancient Battle! Ajax vs Atalanta : Winner is Ajax in 2 rounds. 

Finals
Ancient Battle! Hector vs Ajax : Winner is Hector in 4 rounds.
```

I am guessing it has something to do with -= operator logic and i can't seem to figure it out. Any help?

Hero.cpp

```
#include "Hero.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
namespace sict {

    Hero::Hero()
    {
        m_name[0] = '\0';
        m_health = 0;
        m_attack = 0;

    }



    Hero::Hero(char name[], int health, int attack)
    {

        if (m_name != nullptr || m_name != "") {
            strcpy(m_name, name);

        }
        else {
            m_name[0] = '\0';
        }

        m_attack = attack;
        m_health = health;


    }

    void Hero::operator-=(int attack) {
        if (attack > 0) {
            m_health -= attack;
        }
        if (attack > m_health) {
            m_health = 0;
        }
    }
    bool Hero::isAlive() const {
        if (m_health > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    int Hero::attackStrength() const {
        if (m_attack == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return m_attack;
        }
    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Hero& hero) {
        if (hero.m_name == '\0') {
            os << "No Hero";
        }
        else {
            os << hero.m_name;
        }
        return os;
    }
    const Hero& operator*(const Hero& first, const Hero& second) {
        cout << "Ancient Battle! ";
        cout << first;
        cout << " vs ";
        cout << second;
        cout << " : ";
        Hero A = first;
        Hero B = second;
        const Hero *winner = nullptr;
        int max_rounds = 0;
        while (A.isAlive() && B.isAlive() && max_rounds < 200) {
            max_rounds++;
            A -= B.attackStrength();
            B -= A.attackStrength();

        }

        bool draw;

        if (A.isAlive() && B.isAlive()) { draw = true; }
        else { draw = false; }

        if (draw) {
            winner = &first;
        }
        else if (A.isAlive())
        {
            winner = &first;
        }
        else {
            winner = &second;
        }
        cout << "Winner is ";
        cout << *winner;
        cout << " in " << max_rounds << " rounds. " << endl;
        return *winner;

    }
}
```

Hero.h

```
#ifndef SICT_HERO_H_
#define SICT_HERO_H_
#include <iostream>
namespace sict {
    class Hero {
        char m_name[41];
        int m_health;
        int m_attack;
    public:
        Hero();
        Hero(char name[], int health, int attack);
        void operator-=(int attack);
        bool isAlive() const;
        int attackStrength() const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Hero& hero);
    };
    const Hero& operator*(const Hero& first, const Hero& second);
}
#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hero.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

int main() {

    cout << "Greek Heroes";
    Hero moneyhunger("", 40, 4);
    Hero hercules("Hercules", 32, 4);
    Hero theseus("Theseus", 14, 5);
    Hero oddyseus("Odysseus", 15, 3);
    Hero ajax("Ajax", 17, 5);
    Hero achilles("Achilles", 20, 6);
    Hero hector("Hector", 30, 5);
    Hero atalanta("Atalanta", 10, 3);
    Hero hippolyta("Hippolyta", 10, 2);

    cout << endl << "Quarter Finals" << endl;
    const Hero& greek_winner0 = moneyhunger * hector;
    const Hero& greek_winner1 = achilles * hector;
    const Hero& greek_winner2 = hercules * theseus;
    const Hero& greek_winner3 = oddyseus * ajax;
    const Hero& greek_winner4 = atalanta * hippolyta;

    cout << endl << "Semi Finals" << endl;
    const Hero& greek_winner_semifinal1 = greek_winner1  * greek_winner2;
    const Hero& greek_winner_semifinal2 = greek_winner3  * greek_winner4;

    cout << endl << "Finals" << endl;
    greek_winner_semifinal1 * greek_winner_semifinal2;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger to determine exactly where the program is not doing what you expected.  (In particular, you're familiar with the expected behavior, and it would take me quite a while to reason through all this code to figure out what the results ought to be.)  If you pinpoint that spot but still don't understand what happened, try to reduce the program to a [mcve] built around just the behavior of that one confusing piece.

Comment: `void Hero::operator-=(int attack)` makes no sense, especially given how it is used. Make it return a value.

Comment: It needs to return this and have a Hero& return type. Also you should use an else statement because you have a logic error

Comment: Thank you! fixed this by putting else statement instead of another if for my -= operator

Comment: @SmithKyo `if (m_name != nullptr || m_name != "") { strcpy(m_name, name);` -- Look at this test carefully.   What if `m_name` is a `nullptr`? The second half of the `if` will attempt to be invoked.  The way this is done is checking for if it is not null **and** checking to make sure it isn't empty.

Comment: `Hero A = first;` -- You are returning a reference to a local variable in your `operator *` function.  Thus your code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `char name[]` isn't serious C++. Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The operator needs to return `*this` and have a `Hero&` return type. Also you need to use an else statement because you have a logic error .

Answer (score 0):

You have the function

```
void Hero::operator-=(int attack) {
    if (attack > 0) {
        m_health -= attack;
    }
    if (attack > m_health) {
        m_health = 0;
    }
}
```

This will sometimes reduce health more than once.

Suppose health is 15 and attack is 10. The first if-statement will reduce the health to 5. The second if-statement will then reduce it again to 0.

To avoid this you can do:

```
void Hero::operator-=(int attack) {
    if (attack > 0) {
        if (attack > m_health) {
            m_health = 0;
        } else {
            m_health -= attack;
        }
    }
}
```

This will reduce health to 0 only when the attack is at least as large as the remaining health.